# Where can I play poker?

Tags: far-cry-3

I know that you can play poker in the game. Do I have to unlock a mission to enable it ? Where are the location I could play ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Poker locations unlock like other "activity" locations, when you take over enemy outposts. When you open one, you'd receive a notification.

They look like a spade on your map. You can go to your map and check the legend to filter for poker locations specifically.

Comment: There are also two poker matches you participate in during the main storyline.

Comment: And another one in a side mission. Completing that side mission actually satisfies a requirement for a trophy/achievement, Poker Bully